# Null Pointer exception when calling service method from controller

Tags: grails, groovy, nullpointerexception

I have a method in service class which has to be called from the controller. Both the controller and the service class codes are as below.
folder `grails-app/services`, file `FileFactoryService.groovy`

```
package edu.rev.document
import grails.transaction.Transactional

Class FileFactoryService{
Document document = new Document()    // Domain object
    def build(byte[] fileArray){      
    String str = new String(fileArray, "UTF-8") // UTF encoding as invoice may contain negative values
    String[] lines = str.split("\\r?\\n") 
    document.version = lines[0].substring(0,1)
    document.name = lines[1].substring(0,25)
   }
   return document.properties.collect()
 }
```

Controller Code: folder: `grails-app/controllers`, file: `FileController.groovy`

```
package edu.rev.document
 Class FileController{
    def fileFactoryService            
    def save(){
    def file = request.getFile('file')
    if(file.empty) {
        flash.message = "File cannot be empty"
    } else {
        def myList = fileService.build(file.getBytes())
        }    
    }
```

The error thrown is

`NullPointer exception when processing [POST]/../save
Cannot invoke method build() on NULL object`

Can you please point me to the mistake I might be committing? Let me know if you need any other information

**EDIT**:This is the code. Just a heads up, the same logic when taken out of the service and implemented in the controller itself works perfectly alright. One more thing, when I use the "." operator inside the service (say `document.`), it doesnt show may any auto complete options like `document.name`.

Comment: Are you sure you put your `FileService.groovy` file in the `services/..` folder?

Comment: Yes I did. I use GGTS for the application, so these things are automatically done. But yes, I did verify.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you are showing in your question...

Comment: I think you're going to need to show us more... How are you hitting the controller?  Are you instantiating it yourself (as that would be wrong, and would cause the error you're seeing)?  Is this happening as part of a web request, unit test, or other?

Comment: You code doesn't look like a valid Groovy code (like `Class`, etc), and exception looks different too. I believe you need to show us original code to find the problem

Comment: As Igor says, can you post actual code rather than invalid anecdotal code?

Answer (score 4):

Posting all of your code helps in finding the error. This line in your controller class

`def myList = fileService.build(file.getBytes())`

should be

`def myList = fileFactoryService.build(file.getBytes())`

Answer (score 1):

In your controller class, you declared the service as :

> def fileService

But the name of your service class is :

```
Class FileFactoryService
```

For Grails dependency injection to work, you need to name the variable like your class name :

```
def fileFactoryService
```

Then this should work.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you copy / paste your real code so you avoid typos. Like others said, it's impossible to find the issue you are describing without real code.

Comment: The edited version Is the real code. Its developed for an R&D institute, so I do have to change the names here and there. Rest assured, everything else is same. Thanks anyways.